# Increase Android button's width from right to left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I want button width to be increased from right to left, and not from left to right , what should I do?

For example:

```
Button btn = findviewbyId(R.id.Button1);
btn.setwidth(1000);
```

This will start increasing width from right side of button, but I want it to increase in the opposite direction.

Comment: what about your layout xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one ,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="end"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.btns.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        int i=0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            i=i+50;

            btn.setWidth(i);

            p(i);

        }
        private void p(int i) {

            System.out.println(i);

        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the ***gravity*** and ***layout_gravity*** properties.

Comment: it was too late reply , but anyway the android:gravity="right" worked.

Answer (score 0):

**getting initial width**

```
int initialwidth;
Button btn=findviewbyId(R.id.Button1);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();  
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onGlobalLayout() {  
        this.btn.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);  
       initialwidth = btn.getMeasuredWidth();  
    }  
});
```

then using the differnce between initial width and new width ,set margin left

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
int diff=1000-initialwidth;
params.setMargins(diff, top, right, bottom);
btn.setWidth(1000);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```