# Increase Relative layout width to the left and to the right

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I want my RelativeLayout to spread with both direction left to right and right to left

I've made several research and I've got a answer for left to right spread Animation with ValueAnimator.

```
ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, width);
```

but when I reverse it then it disappears. It works same as

```
ValueAnimator.ofInt(width,0);
```

I've already tried .reverse() function. But this was not a solution.

Is there any idea for Right to Left Animation? Or Do I have to Use a other solution with xml.
But I want to do with dynamically way as much as possible.

**Edit :**
I've made more research and found some way.

[Increase Android button's width from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798191/increase-android-buttons-width-from-right-to-left/32798245)

This is exactly what I want to be worked. But this is something on ViewGroup...

Answer (score 1):

[Increase LinearLayout width from either right or left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257162/increase-linearlayout-width-from-either-right-or-left)

Try this trick

This Logic is like moving left and the width

With this Logic I solved my problem

I used ValueAnimator and animation is from onAnimationUpdate value

```
 params.leftMargin = xParams - (Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue() + width;
 params.width = (Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue();
```

will do the trick